# cannot find libarary error

Tags: libraries, shared-library

I am trying to install a software "W" which requires some non standard packages like "XYZ". I am installing XYZ as instructed in the related site using the following commands

```
./configure -C
make 
make install
```

after installation of XYZ, I use the following commands to install W (as suggested in the related site):

```
env PKG_CONFIG_PATH="installation path for XYZ/lib/pkgconfig" cmake 
make
```

however I get `usr/bin/ld cannot find -lXYZ`. 
I have also tried the following, which returned the same results:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="installation path for XYZ/lib"
```

when I am checking the library list associated with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I see something like the following results:

```
................. libXYZ.la
................. libXYZ.so -> libXYZ.so.1.5.3
................. libXYZ.so.1 -> libXYZ.so.1.5.3
................. libXYZ.so.1.5.3
................. pkgconfig
```

where ....... are some info like date and other things
Does this problem is caused due to the version number of libraries or what? how can i solve it?

Comment: I'd start by examining the output of `cmake` and/or the `CMakeCache.txt` file to see what location (if any) was cached for the library. (I'm hazy on the details of how Cmake works, however it has its own rules for finding packages that may or may not involve `pkg-config`.)

Comment: @steeldriver i cheked it seems to be allright, however, i slightly summerized the quession in fact there are some packeges like xyz, tuv, mln, that are reqiured for W. However some of their libraries are also defined in the others for example xyz/lib has libxyz libtuv,.... can this be the cause of problem?

Comment: Can you try with `export LIBRARY_PATH="installation path for XYZ/lib"`.

Comment: @Thomas yes it did! Thanks it realy made me misreable during the past week! But how? What is difference? And also i have read library_path and ld-path are not good choices especially library path

Comment: Basically `LIBRARY_PATH` is used during linking, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used during runtime. But you will find enough resources with a search engine of your choice. Not sure why that should be considered *not good*. It would be better if the `configure` step would provide such...